# accessing ccsprite from another class

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocos2d-iphone, ccsprite

in A.h i write like this

```
@interface A
{
  CCSprite *loadingSprite;
}

- (void)getTag;

@property (nonatomic, retain) CCSprite *loadingSprite;

@end
```

then in implementation A.m

```
@synthesize loadingSprite

- (id)init
{
 loadingSprite = [CCSprite spriteWithSpriteFrameName:@"loading-icon1.png"];
 [loadingSprite setTag:111];
 [self addChild:loadingSprite];
}

- (void)getTag
{
 NSLog(@"%@ tag %d",[loadingSprite getChildByTag:111] , [loadingSprite getChildByTag:111].tag)
}
```

on another class, B.m i write to access method getTag

```
A *a = [[A alloc] init];
[a getTag];
```

but unfortunately, the NSLog in getTag shows :

```
(null) tag 0
```

how the proper way to access the ccsprite from another class? thanks

Comment: i guess the best way is to make a singleton class for the common sprite being used that way you won't have to initialize it again and again and you can also fetch/ set all properties assigned to that sprite from anywhere you want.

Comment: yes, in the end i use singleton. it's bit too much but i haven't got any clue besides using the sprite as a singleton

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out my tutorial "Strategies for Accessing Other Cocos2D Nodes In The Scene Hierarchy": http://www.learn-cocos2d.com/2012/09/strategies-accessing-cocos2d-nodes-scene-hierarchy/

Comment: whoa, thanks. i'll read it.
maybe it's out of topic. but thanks to you, the first thing i learned cocos2d is by reading your book, very useful book. thanks anyway

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to get child by tag from the sprite. And you want to get this sprite. So, if you wanna use `getChildByTag:`, use

```
[self getChildByTag: tag];
```

instead of

```
[yourSprite getChildByTag: tag];
```

as you add your sprite to `self`. You can get child by tag only from it's parent.

Oh, and change your init method. As you override parent's init, you should call parent's method first.

```
- (id) init
{
    self = [super init];

    if( self != nil )
    {
        // do your initialization here
    }

    return self
}
```

Comment: ah yeah, if i place a log at the end of init method of class A, the log shows the sprite and it's tag.
but still, when i called getTag method from class B, it still shows null and zero, where did i went wrong?

Comment: Use self.loadingSprite in your initialization instead of just loadingSprite. And there is no need to declare it as retain. If you declare it as retain, don't forget to call self.loadingSprite = nil in your dealloc method.

Comment: so i change 
loadingSprite = [CCSprite spriteWithSpriteFrameName:@"loading-icon1.png"];
[loadingSprite setTag:111];
into 
self.loadingSprite = [CCSprite spriteWithSpriteFrameName:@"loading-icon1.png"];
[self.loadingSprite setTag:111];
and still no luck

Comment: if(self = [super init]) is a bit shorter.

Comment: Maybe, but my variant is easier to read. At least, for me and my associates. I always prefer clearer variant.

Comment: in the end i use singleton. well it's bit too much. but thanks for sharing

Answer (score 1):

Another thing - you don't have to retain nodes you add to your class, because cocos2d automatically retains any node when you use `[self addChild:node]` and releases when you release your base node, so better use `@property (nonatomic, assign) CCSprite *loadingSprite;`

And you can use that property to access nodes from another classes - just use `a.loadingSprite` in your example. At all, using tags is not the best solution to access nodes, because when you have a lot of nodes and a lot of tags you might easily get lost there.

Comment: yes, it's king of rough using tag like that. thanks, i'll give it a go